# renderGvis does not work in rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, googlevis

I tried to display a googleVis chart in a rmarkdown page but it doesn't work...  Instead, it displays the R code verbatim in the browser.

**Result**

```
function () 
{
    chart <- func()
    paste(chart$html$chart, collapse = "\n")
}
<environment: 0x5bd7558>
```

**Code**

````
```{r echo=F}
library(googleVis)

df <- data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), val1=c(1,3,4), val2=c(23,12,32))

renderGvis({
  gvisColumnChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2"))
})

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you're still stuck, I'll answer by the way, should it be usuful for someone else.

There are 2 changes to apply at your code:

- add the `op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')` statement to write only the chart component of the HTML file into the output file [check this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleVis/vignettes/Using_googleVis_with_knitr.html)
- add the `results='asis'` declaration so that the *raw* html is returned [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36608234/googlevis-chart-not-rendering-in-rmarkdown)

Therefore your code should instead be (`.Rmd` document):

````
---
title: "testGoogleVis"
output: html_document
---

```{r echo=F, results='asis'}
library(googleVis)
op <- options(gvis.plot.tag='chart')

df <- data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), val1=c(1,3,4), val2=c(23,12,32))

plot(gvisColumnChart(df, xvar="country", yvar=c("val1", "val2")))
```
````

[image: testGoogleVis]